# Sorting multidimensional array but keeping index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am sorting this array

```
$array =
 ( 
     [Scorebord] => Hyperscore [Ontmoeting_ID] => 1540 [ThuisPloeg_ID] => 1257 [UitPloeg_ID] => 1246 [Wedstrijden] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15401 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12669 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 17) 
          [1] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15402 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12713 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 21) 
          [2] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15403 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12656 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 23) 
          [3] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15404 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12912 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 19)
      )
 )
```

with "Speler_Thuis_TSP" as criteria through this code:

```
     usort($json_sorted['Wedstrijden'], function($a,$b){
          $c = $a['Speler_Thuis_TSP'] - $b['Speler_Thuis_TSP'];
          return $c;
     });
```

which gives me this array :

```
 ( 
     [Scorebord] => Hyperscore [Ontmoeting_ID] => 1540 [ThuisPloeg_ID] => 1257 [UitPloeg_ID] => 1246 [Wedstrijden] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15401 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12669 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 17) 
          [1] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15404 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12912 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 19)
          [2] => Array ( 
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15402 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12713 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 21) 
          [3] => Array (
              [Wedstrijd_ID] => 15403 [Speler_Thuis_ID] => 12656 [Speler_Thuis_TSP] => 23) 
      )
 )
```

The problem is the "Wedstrijd_ID" should remain in the original order, ie first 15401, then 15402, 15403 and 15404. Any ideas how to fix that ? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: when you sort your array on `['Speler_Thuis_TSP']`, your `['Wedstrijd_ID']`'s will change order... if you want to go back to the sorted array on  `['Wedstrijd_ID]`'s  you take your original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this solution, you can grab the original order using array_column, and then simple overwrite the new order values by simply replacing the new ordered values with the array_column values.

```
$original_id_order = array_column($json_sorted['Wedstrijden'], 'Wedstrijd_ID');

usort($json_sorted['Wedstrijden'], function($a,$b){
          $c = $a['Speler_Thuis_TSP'] - $b['Speler_Thuis_TSP'];
          return $c;
     });

foreach($json_sorted['Wedstrijden'] as $key => $value){

    $json_sorted['Wedstrijden'][$key]['Wedstrijd_ID'] = $original_id_order[$key];
}
```